# /boot = 100% ; uname -r 4.15.0-137-generic; linux-image-4.15.0-140-generic not install and not remove

Tags: boot, apt, kernel

Very big problem.
The kernel if are run is 4.15.0-137
And the Boot Partition is full.

`df`

```
Filesystem                        1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev                                5083260        0   5083260   0% /dev
tmpfs                               1023012      900   1022112   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  76307268 35715508  37429888  49% /
tmpfs                               5115048        0   5115048   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                  5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                               5115048        0   5115048   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                            999320   979684         0 100% /boot
tmpfs                               1023008        0   1023008   0% /run/user/1000
```

if i run:

```
apt-get remove linux-image-4.15.0-140-generic linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-140-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-140-generic
```

or i run:

```
sudo apt purge linux-headers-4.15.0-137 linux-headers-4.15.0-137-generic linux-image-4.15.0-137-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-137-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-137-generic
```

the answer from the system (Sorry for German)

```
Paket »linux-image-4.15.0-140-generic« ist nicht installiert, wird also auch nicht entfernt.
Paket »linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-140-generic« ist nicht installiert, wird also auch nicht entfernt.
Probieren Sie »apt --fix-broken install«, um dies zu korrigieren.
Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:
 linux-image-generic : Hängt ab von: linux-image-4.15.0-140-generic soll aber nicht installiert werden
                       Hängt ab von: linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-140-generic soll aber nicht installiert werden
E: Unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten. Versuchen Sie »apt --fix-broken install« ohne Angabe eines Pakets (oder geben Sie eine Lösung an).
```

Comment: Translate and repost this is English only site.

Comment: Run `sudo env LC_ALL=C apt` instead of `sudo apt`. It will show English output.

Answer (score 0):

```
l /boot/
total 969916
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   217449 Mai 11  2020 config-4.15.0-101-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   217473 Jun  4  2020 config-4.15.0-106-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   217473 Jun 19  2020 config-4.15.0-108-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   217473 Jul  9  2020 config-4.15.0-111-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   217469 Sep  4  2020 config-4.15.0-117-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   217501 Okt 21 11:12 config-4.15.0-123-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   217458 Nov 23 19:01 config-4.15.0-126-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   217458 Dez  9 07:27 config-4.15.0-128-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   217458 Dez 10 12:54 config-4.15.0-129-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   217458 Jan 12 14:38 config-4.15.0-132-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   217458 Jan 18 18:20 config-4.15.0-135-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   217420 Jan 28 00:31 config-4.15.0-136-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   217420 Feb 19 11:28 config-4.15.0-137-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   217495 Feb 11  2020 config-4.15.0-88-generic
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root     4096 Mär 16 06:59 grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 57951393 Jul  9  2020 initrd.img-4.15.0-101-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 57967651 Jul  9  2020 initrd.img-4.15.0-106-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 57963733 Jul  9  2020 initrd.img-4.15.0-108-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 57974509 Jul 15  2020 initrd.img-4.15.0-111-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 57971294 Sep 16  2020 initrd.img-4.15.0-117-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 58437965 Nov 12 06:25 initrd.img-4.15.0-123-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 58446732 Dez  3 06:06 initrd.img-4.15.0-126-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 58450923 Dez 13 06:32 initrd.img-4.15.0-128-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 58452335 Jan  6 06:53 initrd.img-4.15.0-129-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 58453370 Jan 19 06:26 initrd.img-4.15.0-132-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 58456868 Jan 28 06:17 initrd.img-4.15.0-135-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 58445398 Feb 27 06:26 initrd.img-4.15.0-136-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 58636118 Mär 16 06:59 initrd.img-4.15.0-137-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 57933206 Jul  9  2020 initrd.img-4.15.0-88-generic
drwx------ 2 root root    16384 Aug 21  2019 lost+found
-rw------- 1 root root  4072495 Mai 11  2020 System.map-4.15.0-101-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  4073353 Jun  4  2020 System.map-4.15.0-106-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  4073353 Jun 19  2020 System.map-4.15.0-108-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  4073543 Jul  9  2020 System.map-4.15.0-111-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  4074919 Sep  4  2020 System.map-4.15.0-117-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  4076460 Okt 21 11:12 System.map-4.15.0-123-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  4076876 Nov 23 19:01 System.map-4.15.0-126-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  4076733 Dez  9 07:27 System.map-4.15.0-128-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  4078450 Dez 10 12:54 System.map-4.15.0-129-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  4078450 Jan 12 14:38 System.map-4.15.0-132-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  4078490 Jan 18 18:20 System.map-4.15.0-135-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  4078756 Jan 28 00:31 System.map-4.15.0-136-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  4078677 Feb 19 11:28 System.map-4.15.0-137-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  4069510 Feb 11  2020 System.map-4.15.0-88-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  8380064 Mai 11  2020 vmlinuz-4.15.0-101-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  8380064 Jun  4  2020 vmlinuz-4.15.0-106-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  8380064 Jun 19  2020 vmlinuz-4.15.0-108-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  8380064 Jul  9  2020 vmlinuz-4.15.0-111-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  8388256 Sep  4  2020 vmlinuz-4.15.0-117-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  8384160 Okt 21 11:15 vmlinuz-4.15.0-123-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  8388256 Nov 23 19:08 vmlinuz-4.15.0-126-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  8388256 Dez  9 07:32 vmlinuz-4.15.0-128-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  8388256 Dez 10 13:04 vmlinuz-4.15.0-129-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  8388256 Jan 12 15:33 vmlinuz-4.15.0-132-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  8392352 Jan 18 18:24 vmlinuz-4.15.0-135-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  8396448 Jan 28 02:21 vmlinuz-4.15.0-136-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  8392352 Feb 19 14:17 vmlinuz-4.15.0-137-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  8371864 Feb 11  2020 vmlinuz-4.15.0-88-generic
```

then I have make:

```
/boot# rm *0-88-*
```

after this, I can make this

```
apt --fix-broken install
```

Comment: Is that additional information to your question? if so, please **edit** your question and add it there. Please use the **{}** (code block formatting) when pasting commands and command output.

Comment: Bad way to solve it